# Convert Row into List(String) in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data in Row tuple format -

```
Row(Sentence=u'When, for the first time I realized the meaning of death.')
```

I want to convert it into String format like this -

```
(u'When, for the first time I realized the meaning of death.')
```

I tried like this (Suppose 'a' is having data in Row tupple)-

```
b = sc.parallelize(a)
b = b.map(lambda line: tuple([str(x) for x in line]))
print(b.take(4))
```

But I am getting result something like this -

```
[('W', 'h', 'e', 'n', ',', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'r', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', ' ', 't', 'i', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'z', 'e', 'd', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'm', 'e', 'a', 'n', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 'd', 'e', 'a', 't', 'h', '.')]
```

Do anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With single `Row` (why would you even...) it should be:

```
a = Row(Sentence=u'When, for the first time I realized the meaning of death.')

b = sc.parallelize([a])
```

and flattened with

```
b.map(lambda x: x.Sentence)
```

or

```
b.flatMap(lambda x: x)
```

although `sc.parallelize(a)` is already in the format you need - because you pass `Iterable`, Spark will iterate over all fields in `Row` to create `RDD`

Answer (score 7):

**below is the code:**

```
col = 'your_column_name'
val = df.select(col).collect()
val2 = [ ele.__getattr__(col) for ele in val]
```

Comment: This worked for me with the following adjustment (cleaner): `val2 = [ ele[col] for ele in val]`

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me
1:
`list_val = df.selectExpr("max(Location) as loc").collect() str_val = [e['loc'] for e in list_val][0]`

2:
`row = df.first() string_value = row['columnName']`